# How to attach saiku to an application dashboard

Tags: saiku

i succeeded to add a cube in saiku analysis to visualiz tables, so my next step is to attach saiku to an application Dashboard.
The dashboard was made by HTML, then how i can do this? thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Saiku Dashboard](http://www.meteorite.bi/blog/128) or create your own Dashboard (static) with CSS/HTML/JS using [SaikuEmbed.js](https://github.com/OSBI/saiku/blob/master/saiku-ui/js/saiku/embed/SaikuEmbed.js).